# Javascript returns System.InvalidOperationException: Unexpected new line Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to write a mailto form which has the body already created. For the moment I'm keeping it simple and trying to just put an email, address and name into the body of the email to be sent. When I do this it returns the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unexpected new line

Here's the HTML:

```
<form method='post'  enctype="text/plain">
<b>Name:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="personsName" id="personsName"><br>
<b>E-mail:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="mail" id ="mail"><br>
<b>Address:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="address" id ="address"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="send">
</form>
```

And here's the relevant JavaScript:

```
$(function(){ EGf20a6658.Init(); });

var EGf20a6658 = {

Init: function() {
    if (typeof(OEConfEGf20a6658) === undefined) return;
    var allElements = OEConfEGf20a6658;

    for(var ID in allElements) {
        var $el = $('#'+ID); // The element's main <div> tag
        var properties = allElements[ID]; // element's available properties for JS
        this.InitElement(ID, $el, properties);
    }
},

InitElement: function(ID, $el, properties) {
    
    var name = $('#personsName').val();
    var mail = $('#mail').val();
    var address = $('#address').val();
    
    var message = "Hey " + " How are you? You still at "  + " with the email "  + "?";
    
    var mailtolink = 'mailto:me@domain.com?subject=Regret Permission Form&body=' + encodeURIComponent(message);
    
    $( '#send' ).on( 'click', function(event) {
    $(this).attr('href', mailtolink);
    });
}

};
```

I noticed that the error always returns the value for name.

Here's the full error code:

```
500 - Unexpected new line: k [CRLF].

System.InvalidOperationException: Unexpected new line: k
[CRLF].
   at HttpServer.Tools.StringReader.ReadToEnd(String delimiters)
   at HttpServer.Tools.UrlParser.Parse2(ITextReader reader, Boolean urlDecode)
   at HttpServer.Tools.UrlParser.Parse2(String queryString, Boolean urlDecode)
   at HttpServer.RequestEventArgs.FixPostData(IRequest request)
   at HttpServer.RequestEventArgs..ctor(IHttpContext context, IRequest request, IResponse response)
   at HttpServer.HttpContext.OnRequest(Object sender, FactoryRequestEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at HttpServer.Messages.MessageFactoryContext.OnMessageComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at HttpServer.Messages.Parser.HttpParser.OnComplete()
   at HttpServer.Messages.Parser.HttpParser.GetBody()
   at HttpServer.Messages.Parser.HttpParser.Parse(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at HttpServer.HttpContext.ParseBuffer(Int32 bytesLeft)
   at HttpServer.HttpContext.OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
```

Comment: "name" is a bad name for an element, try to rename the input, and remove the new-line from the message.

Comment: \n How are you? try removing the new line?

Comment: I've tried removing the new lines, I've actually removed all the vars from the mailtolink and I still receive the error.

Comment: I've just added the full javascript file as it has just dawned on me that it may be the initial var name rather than mailtolink

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to fix the issue. I realized I had made the issue too complicated and fixed it using some simple code from Aitor in this [Anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32623868) . I basically just rewrote it to fit the way Aitor had his laid out.