# HTML Email Survey upon button click

Tags: html, forms, email, action

I am trying to email this survey and its results as a string to an email address when the "send Survey" button is clicked. I cannot figure out how to make this action occur. Does anyone have any ideas how to accomplish this? I have tried using the form tag with the action set to mailto:recipient@yahoo.com and the method as get. Is there anything I am missing here? I have read several pages on emailing surveys on HTML button actions. Thanks. I have the following code:

```js
//preset all form values
document.ColorSurvey.Visistor.value = "John Doe";
document.ColorSurvey.State.Selectedindex = 5;
document.ColorSurvey.Password.value = "shhhhh';
document.ColorSurvey.Gender[1].checked = true;
```

```css
.form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 210px;
}

.form label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
}

.form input {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  float: right;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}

label.orange {
  color: orange;
}

label.violet {
  color: violet;
}

label.grey {
  color: grey;
}

label.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

label.red {
  color: red;
}

label.green {
  color: green;
}

label.pink {
  color: pink;
}

label.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<title>
  Color Survey
</title>

<h1>Color Survey</h1>
<form action=”mailto:contact@yourdomain.com” method=”get” enctype=”multipart/form-data” name=”EmailTestForm”>
  <div align="center">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name:">
    <br>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email:">
    <br>
    <label>Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone:">
    <label>EXT:</label>
    <input type="text" name="EXT:" style="width: 45px;">
    <br>
    <label>State:<select id="countrySelect" name="countrySelect">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
     <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
     <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
     <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
     <option value="CA">California</option>
     <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
     <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
     <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
     <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
     <option value="FL">Florida</option>
     <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
     <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
     <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
     <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
     <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
     <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
     <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
     <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
     <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
     <option value="ME">Maine</option>
     <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
     <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
     <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
     <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
     <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
     <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
     <option value="MT">Montana</option>
     <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
     <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
     <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
     <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
     <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
     <option value="NY">New York</option>
     <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
     <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
     <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
     <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
     <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
     <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
     <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
     <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
     <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
     <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
     <option value="TX">Texas</option>
     <option value="UT">Utah</option>
     <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
     <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
     <option value="WA">Washington</option>
     <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
     <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
     <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>
      <br>
      <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Password:">
    <label>Confirm:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Confirm:">
  </div>

  <div align="center">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="favcolors[]" value="cycling" /> black</label>
    <label class='orange'><input type="checkbox" name="favcolors[]" value="orange" /> orange</label>
    <label class='violet'><input type="checkbox" name="favcolors[]" value="violet" /> violet</label>
    <br>
    <label class='grey'><input type="checkbox" name="favcolors[]" value="Grey" /> Grey</label>
    <label class='yellow'><input type="checkbox" name="favcolors[]" value="Yellow" /> Yellow</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="favcolors[]" value="White" /> White</label>
    <br>
    <label class='red'><input type="checkbox" name="favcolors[]" value="red" /> red</label>
    <label class='green'><input type="checkbox" name="favcolors[]" value="green" /> green</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="favcolors[]" value="other" /> other</label>
    <br>
    <label class='pink'><input type="checkbox" name="favcolors[]" value="pink" /> pink</label>
    <label class='blue'><input type="checkbox" name="favcolors[]" value="blue" /> blue</label>
  </div>
  <div align='center'>
    <label>Comments:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Comments:" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Comments:" style="width: 80px;">
    <label>For internal use only</label>
    <br>
    <button>Send Survey</button>
    <button>Clear Form</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create mailto from form with custom fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604812/create-mailto-from-form-with-custom-fields)

Comment: Not really, as far as I know my java code should be working. I am now able to have the form emailed when i click the button ( i changed form action properties) but the string that is supposed to be taken with the javascript is not being sent along with it. Is there something I am missing that is preventing my response string from being sent.

Comment: Virtually all email clients disable JavaScript entirely.

Comment: What you can do from javascript is just to open the email client and add content to it , you cannot send it automatically.

Comment: Ok, do you have any idea how I can attach the results of the survey to the email as a string automatically?

Comment: it is already in the link I mentioned above , you can concatenate the body message with all fields you want to.

Comment: Tried that. It does not work

Comment: First question... what Java? I see no Java in your code, javascript is not even related to Java. Second question... do yo realize all that `mail:to` does is open the users email client and pre-populate some things? To reliably send form information via email, or anything via email for that matter, you will need to get some type of serverside technology involved.

Comment: Also don't use `”` (curly or typographical quotes) in html attributes, use "straight" quotes instead `"`

Comment: "To reliably send form information via email, or anything via email for that matter, you will need to get some type of serverside technology involved." do you mean through the use of ASPX?